# what I am doing wrong in sql query

Tags: sql, db2

```
TRAIN_ID TRAIN_NO SRC_DATE   COACH_ID ASSIGN_COACH_FLAG USER_ID DATE_ADDED              CH_NUMBER USER_TYPE
-------- -------- ---------- -------- ----------------- ------- ----------------------- --------- ---------
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 -        A                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.262         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C1       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.326         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C10      T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.33          1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C11      T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.334         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C12      T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.337         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C13      T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.341         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C14      T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.345         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C2       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.349         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C3       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.353         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C4       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.357         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C5       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.361         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C6       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.364         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C7       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.368         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C8       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.372         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 C9       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.376         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 E1       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.379         1 TS 
 6442 12014    2017-05-14 E2       T                 psaini  2017-05-16 15:20:18.383         1 TS
```

this is the table data.

Result what I want is

```
TRAIN_NO       COACH_ID                     -
 12014          C1  
            C10 
            C11 
            C12 
            C13 
            C14 
            C2  
            C3  
            C4  
            C5  
            C6  
            C7  
            C8  
            C9  
                E2
```

query I am using

```
select distinct train_no, coach_id 
from table
```

Kindly help me why the result is not as per the requirement.

Comment: Why do you want that? If you don't want to show the train number for multiple rows you can do that on the presentation layer rather than writing complex queries on the database.

Comment: but train_no can be change and also for that train_no multiple coaches can be assigned so we have to make complex query.

Comment: Then please show exactly what you want, including changing train numbers etc

Comment: This is NOT something you should try in SQL. **SQL will repeat the train_no on all rows.** SQL is NOT a "make it pretty" report writer.

Comment: Yeah, I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from traindetails;
```

output:

```
TRAINID COACHNAMES
12014        c1
12014       c2
12014       c3
12014       c4
12014       c5
12014       c6
12014       c7
12014       c8
12014       c9
12014       c10
```

based on your requirement the query will be as follows:

```
SELECT  a.COACHNAMES as coah_names ,
             CASE 
                WHEN a.rnk = 1 THEN a.TRAINID
                ELSE NULL
            END AS TRAIN_ID 
  FROM (
                SELECT a.*,
                    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.TRAINID ORDER BY a.COACHNAMES ) rnk
                    FROM traindetails a
                ) a
```

output will be as follows:

```
COAH_NAMES  TRAIN_ID
c1          12014
c10 
c2  
c3  
c4  
c5  
c6  
c7  
c8  
c9
```